# react-js-pagination doesn't have any styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

why react-js-pagination doesn't have any styles
[image]

import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";

```
<Pagination
          hideDisabled
          activePage={this.state.activePage}
          itemsCountPerPage={this.state.limit}
          totalItemsCount={this.state.totalRows}
          pageRangeDisplayed={8}
          onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Pagination
          // add itemClass and LinkClass
          itemClass="page-item"
          linkClass="page-link"
      hideDisabled
      activePage={this.state.activePage}
      itemsCountPerPage={this.state.limit}
      totalItemsCount={this.state.totalRows}
      pageRangeDisplayed={8}
      onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
      />
```